Need formula to get last previous month data when ever I run the SQL query in a specific month(example: if I run report in May, June )
This is regarding on SQL query need small correction or small logic
(CASE WHEN day(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<30 THEN 
         DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(month,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)) 
 ELSE 
         DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(month,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
 END)

For running the report, I used below logic
Every month
For example, from May1st to May15th -> anyone runs the report it gives data from April 01st to till date
If anyone runs report from May 16th to May 31st then report gives data from May 01st to till date
Right now in this way I am populating the data
It needs small correction whenever I run the report irrespective of date it should give me previous month data only
For example: In this month, if I run report data should come from April 01st to April 30th only
Highly appreciated if I get the this formula corrected. please help
(CASE WHEN day(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)<30 THEN 
      DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(month,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)) 
 ELSE 
      DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(month,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
 END)


Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Date functions often DBMS-specific

Use Case expression and some date math:
--    D a t e    M a t h :
-- same date previous month (6) - todays day of month (6) + 1 equals first day of previous month
-- (DATE) 06.04.24              - (NUMBER) 6              + 1 = (DATE) 01.04.24
-- ----------------------------   -----------------------   - ----------------------------------
   ADD_MONTHS(Trunc(TODAY), -1) - EXTRACT(DAY From TODAY) + 1 = 01.04.24 for TODAY = 06.05.24                                  

WITH     -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    dates AS
        ( Select 1 as ID, DATE '2024-05-06' as TODAY From Dual Union All
          Select 2 as ID, DATE '2024-05-16' as TODAY From Dual
        )

... use execution date instead of TODAY
--    S Q L :
Select      ID, TODAY,
            Case When EXTRACT(DAY From TODAY) <= 15 Then ADD_MONTHS(Trunc(TODAY), -1) - EXTRACT(DAY From TODAY) + 1 
            Else TRUNC(TODAY) - EXTRACT(DAY From TODAY) + 1
            End as DATE_FROM,
            --
            Trunc(TODAY) as DATE_TO
From        dates

/*    R e s u l t : 
ID TODAY    DATE_FROM DATE_TO 
-- -------- --------- --------
 1 06.05.24 01.04.24  06.05.24
 2 16.05.24 01.05.24  16.05.24   */

